# How do I report a bug on Ubuntu One in Windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu-one, ubuntu-one-windows

Hi i am using ubuntu One in Windows 7 Professional 32bit. It's fresh installed just because i just got it from my university msdnaa. I installed UbuntuOne from the website but i couldn't login from the program. I have tried to login from website and it was successfull. i have tried close the program and tried to start again. But it even became more worse because the agreement button was disabled. I want to report bug but i don't know because i'm using Windows right now. please help, some myworks are stored there. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would probably be to visit the [Ubuntu One Launchpad page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone) and see if your bug has already been reported.

If so click the bug report and select `This bug affects X people. Does this bug affect you?`  at the top left.

If not then click `Report a Bug` at the top right and provide more details.

See also:

- https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-report-a-bug-for-windows/